# Multiplatform document app created with Xcode 14.0 beta (14A5228q) doesn't create document on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

1. Open Xcode 14.0 beta (14A5228q)
2. Create new Multiplatform document app.
3. Run the iOS simulator.
4. Create a new document

Notice error: "the document could not be opened"

[image: iOS Simulator]

Does anyone happen to know a workaround?

Have reported to apple in the meantime: FB10341333

---

**Update 1:**

@asperi discovered that it does work if you switch to the `Browse` tab first.
I believe this is then only a bug with the `Recents` tab as it was previously working on Xcode 13.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has fixed this in `Version 14.0 beta 2 (14A5229c)`

Comment: The issue appeared again. (Xcode 14.3)

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug. You try to create it in `Recents` which is not a real folder, so does not allow to write. Tap `Browse` tab and there you will be able to create new document.

Like below:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you are correct given that button exists when you're on the recents tab indicating that Apple wants you to be able to create a document from the recents tab.
Further more tapping + in Xcode 13.4 in the recents tab works. See updated answer.
Regardless you've assisted in by showing a workaround by way of going to the browse tab.